# How to resend bounced email messages using mutt

Tags: linux, email, mutt, email-bounces

#### Background

- An email relaying issue was resolved.
- 32 email messages to sponsors had bounced to root.
- I copied /var/mail/root to /tmp/root.
- I deleted irrelevant messages from /tmp/root (using mutt).
- All the bounced messages had the same sender.

#### Requirements

An efficient way to do the following for all 32 messages:

1. Extract the original message from the bounce message.
2. Send the message as the original sender to the original recipients, including the original bcc.
3. Make the sponsors notice nothing except that there was a delay in delivery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In mutt, start in the message index listing the bounce notification messages of interest.
2. With the cursor on a bounce notification message, type v to open the Attachment Menu for the bounce notification message.
3. The Attachment Menu lists all attachments. A description of each attachment is shown. The subject of the original message is its description.
4. Press j to move the cursor to the attachment identified by its description as the original message. Do not open the attachment.
5. Press Escape-e to start the resend-message dialog.
6. The body of the original message opens in the mutt editor.
7. Press : to open the editor command line.
8. Press q and Enter to exit message composition.
9. Press y to resend the message.
10. Press q to return to the message index.
11. Use j or other appropriate keys to move the cursor to another bounce notification of interest.
12. As needed, go back to #2.